# Gitlab не отправляет сообщения. Errno::EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host - connect(2) for "ip" port 25)

Tags: docker, gitlab, sendmessage

Доброго времени суток.

В общем поставили мне задачу перенести gitlab на новый сервер(на виртуалку centos 8). Сделал всё по инструкции т.е. установил такую же версию на новый сервер, сделал бекап, восстановил на новом, полностью скопировал каталог "config" и обновил до последней версии. Gitlab работает как и на старом, всё ок за исключением того, что не отправляются сообщения.

Gitlab устанавливался в Docker.

Настройки для внешнего SMTP в gitlab.rb:

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "ip внешнего smtp"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 25
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "ip внешнего smtp"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = false
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'gitlab@xxx.ru'
```

Через rails console пробую отправить тестовое сообщение:

```
Notify.test_email('xxx@xxx.ru', 'Hello World', 'This is a test message').deliver_now
```

и получаю ошибку:

```
Errno::EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host - connect(2) for "ip внешнего smtp" port 25)
```

на старом такой проблемы не было.

firewall:

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 3389/tcp 3389/udp 25/tcp 25/udp 22/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
    rule family="ipv4" source address="172.18.0.0/16" accept
    rule family="ipv4" source address="172.27.0.0/16" accept
    rule family="ipv4" source address="172.18.0.1/16" accept
    rule family="ipv4" source address="172.17.0.1/16" accept
    rule family="ipv4" source address="172.17.0.2/32" accept
    rule family="ipv4" source address="10.144.0.0/16" accept
```

хотя на старом я не добавлял ни 25 порт ни правила.

Установил "mailx" и попробовал через него отправить, так:

```
echo "Test text" | mail -s "Test title" -S smtp="ip внешнего smtp:25" xxx@xxx.ru
```

письмо приходит!

Возможно проблема в docker'е, но документация уверяет, что проблем с внешним миром не должно быть.
В gitlab'е я не знаю что ещё можно настроить. Возможно для виртуалки какие то доп настройки нужны.

Любая информация приветствуется. Спасибо!

Comment: Как сам gitlab разворачивался? Можно пример команды или docker-compose?

Comment: docker run --detach 
 --hostname  <ip сервера> 
 --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 10022:22 
 --name gitlab 
 --restart always 
 --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab 
 --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab 
 --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab 
 gitlab/gitlab-ce:13.3.5-ce.0

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить 25 порт к публикуемым портам gitlab при разворачивании gitlab в контейнере:

```
docker run --detach --hostname <ip сервера> \
--publish 25:25 \
--publish 443:443 \
--publish 80:80 \
--publish 10022:22 \
--name gitlab \
--restart always \
--volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
--volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
--volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
gitlab/gitlab-ce:13.3.5-ce.0
```

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: Лучше, конечно, для такого проекта разработайте конфигурацию docker-compose. Это сильно облегчит Вам жизнь.

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint gitlab (6a29881eed3b8cbc4ec00dce0aba539325d164b7dbf73b2c7a6db88aa7ba7c52): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:25: bind: address already in use буду разбираться кто занимает порт. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы можете перенести порт на любой другой, например 10025, если то что занимает порт очень сильно нужно) --publish 10025:25

Comment: Я так и сделал). Проверяю

Comment: Всё равно эта ошибка(

Comment: Какой командой отправляете запрос?

Comment: И как прокинули порт?

Comment: через rails console Notify.test_email('xxx@xxx.ru', 'Hello World', 'This is a test message').deliver_now ,  --publish 10025:25

Comment: Я не силён в linux могу делать что то не правильно. Если подскажете ,что сделать нужно буду очень признателен

Comment: попробуйте echo "Test text" | mail -s "Test title" -S smtp="ip внешнего smtp:10025" xxx@xxx.ru

Comment: Не отправляет. Вот что выдаёт: could not connect: Connection refused
"/home/mylogin/dead.letter" 11/310
. . . message not sent.

Comment: На 25 порту висел postfix, я его отключил за ненадобностью. Сделал с параметром --publish 25:25 получаю ту же ошибку. Docker теперь прослушивает 25 но на tsp6 может в этом проблема?

Comment: Что такое tsp6? ipv6?

Comment: и исключите из команды для развертывания --hostname <ip сервера>

Comment: Так же можно попробовать запустить с сетью хоста, нужно будет убрать все порты (-- publish) и вместо этого прописать --network host. Так контейнер не получит собственный ip-addres, и будет работать в сети хостовой ОС

Comment: --network host помогло. Спасибо большое!